# redirect any .xml to sitemap.xml via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having an unusual issue on my website: if I open `example.com/anyname.xml`, it opens an automated sitemap. To avoid this issue I am trying to redirect all `*.xml` to `sitemap.xml` as my actual sitemap URL is `example.com/sitemap.xml`.

My question is: is there any way to achieve this? I am trying the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(a-z)\.xml$ [R=301,L]
```

This approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(a-z)\.xml$ [R=301,L]
> ```

This directive is incomplete (you are missing a 2nd argument - the *substitution* string - the redirect target). However, the regex `^(a-z)\.xml$` is also incorrect, so it won't match the request anyway.

To redirect any request for `.xml` "files" in the root directory to `sitemap.xml` (excluding `sitemap.xml` itself) you could do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^sitemap$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.xml$ /sitemap.xml [R=301,L]
```

The preceding condition (`RewriteCond` directive) ensures that we don't try to redirect `/sitemap.xml` to itself - which would result in a redirect loop.

The `$1` backreference contains the value matched by the parenthesised group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `([^/]+)`.

You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Note that this needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress code block.

Comment: RewriteRule ^.*\.xml$ /sitemap.xml [L,R=301] this code worked for me

Comment: @UsmanKhan But that would result in a redirect-loop unless you have some other directives (or front-end proxy perhaps) that prevent it, so is not a transferable solution. The solution presented in my answer is preferable. You need to prevent `/sitemap.xml` being redirected to itself, as mentioned in my answer. I would be curious to see your complete `.htaccess` file, since that one-liner cannot possibly work by itself.